# Why do we specify the path in ExtractTemporaryFiles function in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, documentation, pascalscript

I've been reading through Inno Setup documentation and got confused about why do we specify the path in `ExtractTemporaryFiles` function if according to the documentation it *extracts the files matching the wildcard specified by Pattern from the `[Files]` section to a temporary directory.*? If we have this `Source: "Readme.txt"; Flags: dontcopy` in the `[Files]` section why do we type `ExtractTemporaryFiles('{tmp}\Readme.txt')` in the `[Code]` section? Is that a mistake or I just don't understand how this function works? The same applies to the `ExtractTemporaryFile` procedure.

Here's the code from `ExtractTemporyFile` page:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "Readme.txt"; Flags: dontcopy noencryption

[Code]
function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
var
  S: AnsiString;
begin
  { Show the contents of Readme.txt (non Unicode) in a message box }
  ExtractTemporaryFile('Readme.txt');
  if LoadStringFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Readme.txt'), S) then
  begin
    MsgBox(S, mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;

  Result := True;
end;
```

And here's the code from `ExtractTemporaryFiles` page:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "Readme.txt"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Code]
function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
var
  S: AnsiString;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  { Show the contents of Readme.txt (non Unicode) in a message box }
  ExtractTemporaryFiles('{tmp}\Readme.txt');
  if LoadStringFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Readme.txt'), S) then
  begin
    MsgBox(S, mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;

  { Extract all MyProg files and launch it. Note how {app} is left unexpanded. }
  ExtractTemporaryFiles('{app}\MyProg.*');
  ExecAsOriginalUser(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\')+'{app}\MyProg.exe', '', '',
    SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);

  Result := True;
end;
```

In the first case we have:

```
[Files]
Source: "Readme.txt"; Flags: dontcopy noencryption
[Code]
ExtractTemporaryFile('Readme.txt');
```

And in the second one we have:

```
[Files]
Source: "Readme.txt"; Flags: dontcopy
[Code]
ExtractTemporaryFiles('{tmp}\Readme.txt');
```

What's the difference between those two? (`noencryption` flag does not count)
Why do we need to specify the `{tmp}` constant in the second case if we already extracting from there? In order to be able to use those methods correctly I need to have a clear understanding of the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific answer to your question:

> Why do we type `ExtractTemporaryFiles('{tmp}\Readme.txt')` in the `[Code]` section?

The `{tmp}` reference in the `ExtractTemporaryFiles` example code is apparently required for the `ExtractTemporaryFiles` function, although this is undocumented. The `{tmp}` reference is not present in the [documentation sample code for the `ExtractTemporaryFile` procedure](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_extracttemporaryfile):

```
[Files]
Source: "Readme.txt"; Flags: dontcopy noencryption

[Code]
function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
var
  S: AnsiString;
begin
  // Show the contents of Readme.txt (non Unicode) in a message box
  ExtractTemporaryFile('Readme.txt');
  if LoadStringFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Readme.txt'), S) then
  begin
    MsgBox(S, mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;

  Result := True;
end;
```

The only differences that I can see between `ExtractTemporaryFile` and `ExtractTemporaryFiles` are:

1. `ExtractTemporaryFile` only extracts one file and has no return value
2. `ExtractTemporaryFiles` extracts filenames based on a wildcard, and returns type `integer` (number of files extracted), and apparently requires a directory name prefix to disambiguate the filename(s) being extracted (although this is not documented)

Comment: And what about this `ExtractTemporaryFiles('{app}\MyProg.*');`? Do we need the `{app}` here or is it a mistake in documentation as well?

Comment: No, because in that case the files exist in `{app}` and the function copies them to `{tmp}` for a different purpose.

Comment: Note to readers: This answer should not have any downvotes because it is correct.

Answer (score 4):

With `ExtractTemporaryFiles` (contrary to `ExtractTemporaryFile`), you need to use the full value of the `DestDir` parameter (in addition to the filename) to select the correct copy of the file, in case there are multiple files with the same name in the installer. On the contrary, `ExtractTemporaryFile` will always extract the first file with the given name.

So having this:

```
[Files]
Source: "one\readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}\one"
Source: "two\readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}\two"
Source: "three\readme.txt"; Flags: dontcopy
```

- To extract the `one\readme.txt`, use: `ExtractTemporaryFiles('{app}\one\readme.txt')`
- To extract the `two\readme.txt`, use: `ExtractTemporaryFiles('{app}\two\readme.txt')`
- To extract the `three\readme.txt`, use: `ExtractTemporaryFiles('{tmp}\readme.txt')`
  (`Flags: dontcopy` implies `DestDir: {tmp}` for some reason)