# Extracting files with same name from installer during Inno Setup InitializeSetup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

This is my file section

```
Source: "Deployment\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll"; DestDir: "{app}\x64"
Source: "Deployment\x64\System.Data.SQLite.dll"; DestDir: "{app}\x64"
Source: "Deployment\x64\System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll"; DestDir: "{app}\x64"
Source: "Deployment\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll"; DestDir: "{app}\x86"; DestName
Source: "Deployment\x86\System.Data.SQLite.dll"; DestDir: "{app}\x86"
Source: "Deployment\x86\System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll"; DestDir: "{app}\x86"
```

I need to a check list after the first window of Inno Setup appears. For that I have called this function

```pascal
function RunCheckListApp(): Boolean;
var
  resultCode: Integer;
  source: string;
  destination: string;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('Insync.eConnect.InstallerPreRequisiteCheck.exe');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('APPSeConnect.Communications.dll');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('InSync.eConnect.APPSeCONNECT.dll');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.dll');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('Newtonsoft.Json.dll');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('System.Data.SQLite.dll');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('System.Data.SQLite.dll');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('InSync.eConnect.NLogModule.dll'); 
  destination:=ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Adapters');
  CreateDir(destination);
  destination:=ExpandConstant('{tmp}\x86');
  CreateDir(destination);
  destination:=ExpandConstant('{tmp}\x64');
  CreateDir(destination);
  ExtractTemporaryFiles('{tmp}\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll');

  destination := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Adapters\InSync.eConnect.NLogModule.dll')
  source := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\InSync.eConnect.NLogModule.dll');
  FileCopy(source, destination, False);
  DeleteFile(source);

  Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Insync.eConnect.InstallerPreRequisiteCheck.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, resultCode);
  if resultCode > 0
  then begin
    Result:= true;
  end
  else
  begin
    Result:= false;
  end;
end;
```

in `InitializeSetup` function.
The app that I am trying to run requires the DLLs in the corresponding folder to function properly.

`Deployment\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll` to `{app}\x64`
`Deployment\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll` to `{app}\x86`
These are files are copied.
Now the app `Insync.eConnect.InstallerPreRequisiteCheck.exe` requires the same DLLs in the same folders to work.
I am trying to extract those DLLs that have the same name to temporary folder and have the same structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`ExtractTemporaryFiles`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_extracttemporaryfiles) takes a full path as specified by `DestDir` parameter (with unexpanded constants). It still extracts to `{tmp}`.

```pascal
ExtractTemporaryFiles('{app}\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll');
```

Related question: [Why do we specify the path in ExtractTemporaryFiles function in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63343034/850848)