# Inno Setup ExtractTemporaryFiles to specific directory

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm new to Inno Setup, but I want to write some files to the temp directory temporarily, but in a directory structure:

```
tmp\App.exe
tmp\lic\readme.txt
tmp\cfg\configfile.txt
```

Code below is only for the `tmp\lic\readme.txt` file:

```
[Files]
Source: "\\Mac\Home\Desktop\License\Readme.txt"; Flags: dontcopy
```

```pascal
[Code]
function InitializeSetup: Boolean;

begin
  if not DirExists(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\lic')) then
    CreateDir(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\lic'));

  ExtractTemporaryFiles('{tmp}\lic\Readme.txt');
end;
```

The directory `lic` is created but I get an error message when extracting the readme.txt file:

> Exception: Internal error: ExtractTemporaryFiles: No files matching "{tmp}\lic\Readme.txt" found.

If I do not use the directory `lic` I do not get this error message.
Is it not possible to temporarily extract a file to a directory in the `tmp` folder?

Answer (score 1):

The argument of [`ExtractTemporaryFiles`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_extracttemporaryfiles) specifies the file to extract, not the destination path. You cannot choose the destination path. The file is always extracted directly to `{tmp}`.

See also [Extracting files with same name from installer during Inno Setup InitializeSetup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72038194/850848)

---

Two approaches you can try:

- Move the file using [`RenameFile`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_renamefile), after you extract it; or
- Extract the file using `[Files]` section, instead of using the code.

  ```
  [Files]
  Source: "\\...\Readme.txt"; Dest: {tmp}\lic\readme.txt
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work... my installer does something similar. An alternative to using `ExtractTemporaryFiles` is to have the `[Files]` entries deploy to `tmp` yourself. Example:

```
[Files]
Source: "sourcefolder\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Excludes: "sourcefolder\sometempfile"
Source: "sourcefolder\sometempfile"; DestDir: "{tmp}\somefolder"
```

Be mindful of the `Excludes` section of the second line.

Then you can refer to those temp files elsewhere in the installer, for instance:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\somefolder\sometempfile"; Flags: ...
```

This approach may avoid scripting code entirely.

Files placed in `{tmp}` get cleaned up automatically:

> `{tmp}`
>
> Temporary directory used by Setup or Uninstall. This is not the value
> of the user's TEMP environment variable. It is a subdirectory of the
> user's temporary directory which is created by Setup or Uninstall at
> startup (with a name like "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\IS-xxxxx.tmp"). All files
> and subdirectories in this directory are deleted when Setup or
> Uninstall exits. During Setup, this is primarily useful for extracting
> files that are to be executed in the [Run] section but aren't needed
> after the installation.

https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts

(Note that in real code I would `#define` folders, the the temp filename, etc. as constants and use that everywhere.)